# I've changed the permissions for my WindowsApps folder, and now no program in it will run

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions, file-permissions

I didn't save the original permissions, so I'm hoping that there's a way to fix this without having to reinstall Windows 10. I cannot access some of the folders within WindowsApps.

Examples of things not running -- Xbox App Services, Pandora both receive "parameter is incorrect" errors. Xbox Game Pass App will not allow downloads; attempting to launch games leads to the opening of the Xbox App Services download in the Windows Store.

Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 0):

if it's not too late. I think you need to give back ownership to NT service\TrustedInstaller

and make sure TrustedInstaller & System get full controll on all the files

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/restore-windowsapps-permissionss-to/464e65c1-6690-493b-8cf6-c85a5ac5468a

Comment: 'Twas too late, but that's okay. Everything ended up fine and it didn't take me too long to reinstall/sort everything out. Thank you for your answer, though! I do believe I tried to give permissions back to TrustedInstaller (specifically) & probably System, too, but in the end, it didn't help :/ I ended up reinstalling to save myself from the stress & time waste. Again, though, thank you!